# Python warnings are not shown in VSCode notebooks

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm not sure when this started to happen, but I realized that Python warnings are not shown in the Jupiter notebook cells inside VSCode. to reproduce the problem, use the code below:

```
import warnings  
warnings.warn('Warning Message')
```

this gives me nothing when I run it inside a cell, but when I run it from the VSCode terminal (from a `.py` code), then I get:

```
 UserWarning: Warning Message
  warnings.warn('Warning Message')
```

my `.vscode/settings.json` just contains: `{  "python.pythonPath": "venv/bin/python" }`

I'm using `Python 3.8` and the Python extension `2020.5.80290` inside VSCode v. `1.45.1`

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This is working as intended based on how Python's default [warnings filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter) operates. You can [override the default filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html#overriding-the-default-filter) in a couple of ways depending on what you're trying to accomplish. For instance, if you want warnings to show up once, then you can do `warnings.simplefilter("default")`.

Comment: Thanks. I do use `simplefilter` but I shouldn't need it. But why do you think it's "working as intended"? the above code prints the warning in the terminal and not in the notebook editor. In fact, the VSCode team just confirmed that it's a bug.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood. Your question didn't suggest to me that it was printing to the terminal _while_ you were executing in a notebook; I read it as you tested it outside a notebook and the warning worked as intended.

Comment: no worries. Thanks for your answer though. That's the only temp solution that works for now